# How do I trigger a timestamp to be set when a column is updated?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

I've got a table called Card:

```
Card:
id (char(10))
points (int)
activated (bool)
activationDate(DateTime)
```

As default, activated is set to false. What I would like to do is to set activationDate first time when after update of the card happens activated is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

may be something like this

```
create trigger TriggerName
on Card
for update as
if update(activated )
     begin
         if exists (select activated from card
         where activated= false  && ID =SomeValue)
     begin
         rollback trigger with
         raiserror 24004 "Update failed "
     end
     else
     begin
         update Card
         set activationDate= GETDATE() Where ID=someValue
     end
    end
```